# Inserting linebreak in the title attribute using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

**Question:**
I need to put a linebreak inside my tooltip so it's not all on one line. I use [tooltipsy](http://tooltipsy.com/) to generate my tooltips. It works by using the title attribute on any anchor tags with the class "hastipy" as the content of the tooltip.

So the code:

```
<a href="http://tooltipsy.com/" class="hastipy" title="Click here to go to the tooltipsy website">
     tooltipsy
</a>
```

Would be a link showing the text "tooltipsy" and when you hover over it, it would show "Click here to go to the tooltipsy website" in a tooltip.

However, what if I want to put a linebreak inside the tooltip?

This code:

```
<a href="http://tooltipsy.com/" class="hastipy" title="Click here to <br /> go to the tooltipsy website">
     tooltipsy
</a>
```

returns a bunch of errors when you validate it at http://validator.w3.org

So I came up with this javascript/jQuery (written by Jason Gennaro):

```
$('a').each(function(){
    var a = $(this).attr('title');
    var b = a.replace('lineBreak','\n');
    $(this).attr('title', b);
});
```

this code uses a keyword (lineBreak in this case) and replaces it with `\n`(<-- linebreak?) so my code passes validation and still has the linebreak in it.

And this code works on jsfiddle ([here is the example](http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/qRQaq/2/)), but on my website inside the tooltip, it doesn't. It inserts the `\n`, but it doesn't remove the "lineBreak" like it's supposed to.

Can anyone offer an explanation for this or even a possible fix for it?

**Note:**
I don't want a suggestion for another tooltip method, tooltipsy is working perfectly for everything I need.

**Result:**
As it turns out, just using `&lt;br /&gt;` instead of `<br />` worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a global replace call: `.replace(/lineBreak/g,'\n');`.

If you want to add `<br />` in your title attribute, use: `&lt;br /&gt;` (html entities).

Also, JQuery automatically wraps the JavaScript inside `$(document).ready(...)`. You should do the same:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //HTML-modifying code here.
});
```

Comment: Wow, &lt;br /&gt; worked perfectly, thank you very much. I can't believe the solution was so simple =S